# The SQL Server DTS Connection2 object has an undocumented property, UseDSL. What does it do?

Tags: c#, dts

I'm building a wrapper for DTS around the Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPkg80 (the RCW generated from DTSPKG80.DLL). Inside the RCW, on the Connection2 interface, the property "UseDSL" is defined.  This property is not in the SQL Server Books Online documentation, and googling it just found a bunch of "fix my code" listings where people have set it to false.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25872&seqNum=4).  The author of the article asked Microsoft what it is for.  And they said it has to do with a "Data Source Link file to hold the name of a data source file if you use one."  The property is a boolean value so I would assume it means whether or not to use a data source link file.